# Create Directories with File permissions - Java

Tags: java, create-directory

I'm trying to create Directories locally with specific permissions, but it doesn't work in some cases and reverts to specific permissions.

This is my code

```
Path path = Paths.get(dir);
            
Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rwxrw-rw-");
            System.out.println("Permissions are " + PosixFilePermissions.asFileAttribute(perms).value());
            Files.createDirectories(path, PosixFilePermissions.asFileAttribute(perms));
```

The directory created reverts to the default permissions

```
 drwxr--r--    3 user  staff     96 Apr 18 18:16 testing
```

My umask was 022, I changed it to 000, but it still makes no difference when I create a directory from my application. There is a difference as long as I create it directly on the Terminal.

It works in specific cases, as long as I don't provide write access to the group and everyone else. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `dir`?  Does it have multiple path components?

Comment: dir is /Users/user/testing/directory

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I might have figured it out with other answers on here.

If I run `mkdir 755 testing`, the permissions are still

`drwxr-xr-x    2 user  staff     64 Apr 18 19:10 testing`

This is because my umask is 022

This impacts any file or directory created in a Unix based OS.

To fix this programmatically, I'm iterating over my directories until the user home and setting the permissions after creation

```
        Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(dir));
        Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rwxrw-rw-");
        while(!path.toAbsolutePath().equals(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home")))) {
            Files.setPosixFilePermissions(path, perms);
            path = path.getParent();
        }
```

Comment: syntax of `chmod` is wrong - you are actually creating two directories `755`  and `testing`, the correct syntax is `mkdir -m 755 testing`. BTW, that looks like Java's `createDirectories` API is mimicking [POSIX API](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html): "mode specifies the mode for the new directory.  It is modified by the process's umask in the usual way... mode & ~umask & 0777", that is unfortunate, cause both you and many other developers are expecting another behaviour: since we have specified permissions we expect directory/file should be created with those permissions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).